# How to concatenate strings into a single command?

Tags: macros, strings

I'd like to concatenate several parts of math text into a single command, and i read a great solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26334/how-to-concatenate-strings-to-e-g-create-commands-that-return-lists) on this site, allowing me to create this working example of what i mean :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}

\def\reptemp{I love rain}
\global\edef\reptemp{\reptemp, but not too much.}

\begin{document}
\reptemp
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately for some reason it refuses to work with more complex things in it, for example

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}

\def\reptemp{I {\it love} rain}
\global\edef\reptemp{\reptemp, but \bf{not} too much.}

\begin{document}
\reptemp
\end{document}
```

produce the following error message

```
! Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \inaccessible 
l.16 \reptemp
?
```

Of course i'd like to concatenate complex things by this method (environment, enumerate, etc) and i wonder if its possible.

Comment: In addition to Marco's point about `\bf`, you should also be careful with local _versus_ global definitions. Either the macro is local (so `\def` and `\edef`), or global (so `\gdef` and `\xdef`, as 'abbreviations' for `\global\def` and `\global\edef`).

Comment: See also, [expansion - How to prepend and append tokens to a macro definition in the current scope only? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/342506/how-to-prepend-and-append-tokens-to-a-macro-definition-in-the-current-scope-only/342511#342511) ; [macros - Using a command to append data to another one - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/317778/using-a-command-to-append-data-to-another-one)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

What you want to achieve can be done in several ways. First of all let me start with a small hint: The commands `\bf` and `it` are obsolete and they don't have an argument. Please see this answer: [Despite using backslash dollar sign, error persists](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29448/despite-using-backslash-dollar-sign-error-persists/29449#29449)

---

First of all you have to decide whether to save the contents in a token list register or a command. The differences and some explanation to your question are well explained by the great answer of Joseph Wright.
[Is \toks necessary to define \g@addto@macro? Can token registers be avoided in generel?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39747/is-toks-necessary-to-define-gaddtomacro-can-token-registers-be-avoided-in-g)

---

### Using a command:

Approach 1: using `\g@addto@macro`:

`\g@addto@macro` is defined in the LaTeX Kernel. Based on the protected sign `@` you have to use `\makeatletter` ... `\makeatother`, see: [What do \makeatletter and \makeatother do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\makeatletter
\def\reptemp{I \textit{love} rain}
\g@addto@macro\reptemp{, but \textbf{not} too much.}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\reptemp
\end{document}
```

Approach 2: using package [`etoolbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox):

The package `etoolbox` defines some helper macros to add new information to a given command. The material can be added before and after the command. Egreg provides a more robust package with the same  functionality. The package is called [`xpatch`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xpatch). He also provides a more powerful package with is declared as *experimental version*, the package [`regexpatch`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/regexpatch).

Here an example with `etoolbox`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\def\reptemp{I \textit{love} rain}
\appto\reptemp{, but \textbf{not} too much.}
\begin{document}
\reptemp
\end{document}
```

The package `etoolbox` provides more useful functionality and can be loaded with `xpatch` too.

---

A special and new modern way is the usage of macros of the project LaTeX3 and the language `expl3`. Here you can work with token register as well as sequences. The range is really big. The usage of the new syntax needs some special handling which is explained in the short manual [`expl3`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/expl3). Of course you will find a lot of related questions here at tex.stackexchange.

Answer (score 15):

Just an addition to Marco Daniel's excellent answer.

The technique with `\edef` is perfectly fine if all we need is to append (or prepend, or both) to a string of *characters*. It can work with other tokens, but let's limit ourselves to a simple application:

```
\def\mystring{} % initialize
\def\extendmystring#1#2{\edef\mystring{#1\mystring#2}}
```

Then

```
\extendmystring{I love rain}{}
\extendmystring{}{, but not too much.}
\extendmystring{``}{''}
```

would result in `\mystring` expanding to

```
``I love rain, but not too much.''
```

However this is *not* the right tool if you want to preserve the *structure* of what we're storing.

The command `\textit` (which should be used instead of `\it` in your example) *expands* into the instructions needed for persuading TeX into printing the argument in italic type. Even if `\textit` survived in `\edef`, you'd lose some information.

Let's see an example which somewhat works with `\edef`. The code

```
\def\mand#1#2{#1 and #2} % "macro and"
\def\mystring{I love \mand{rain}{snow}} % reinitialize
\extendmystring{``}{, but not too much.''}
```

will result in `\mystring` expanding to

```
``I love rain and snow, but not too much.''
```

and the information that "rain" and "snow" are arguments to `\mand` is completely lost. In a real world application, one might rely on having `\mand` in the replacement text and *redefine* it before expanding (using) `\mystring`; if `\mand` is retained, it would be easy to say

```
\def\mand#1#2{#2}
```

and using `\mystring` would print

> ``I love snow, but not too much.''

while keeping the information intact in `\mystring`. This *won't* happen with the `\edef` technique.

The problem is that `\edef` expands macros (expandable tokens, to be precise) all the way down to unexpandable tokens. Macros like `\textit` (as well as the obsolete `\it`) *don't survive* an `\edef` for reasons that are rather difficult to explain in a few words.

If you want to preserve information, then the `\preto` and `\appto` road is surely better.

Answer (score 4):

this will work:

```
\documentclass{report}

\def\reptemp{I {\itshape love} rain}
\expandafter\def\expandafter\reptemp\expandafter{\reptemp, but {\bfseries not} too much.}

\begin{document}
\reptemp
\end{document}
```

it expands first the old definition of `\reptemp` before defining the new one

Answer (score 1):

With [`functional`](https://ctan.org/pkg/functional) package, you can write the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}

\usepackage{functional}

\TlSet \reptemp {I {\itshape love} rain}
\TlPutRight \reptemp {, but \textbf{not} too much.}

\begin{document}

\reptemp

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The macro `\reptemp` needs to be expanded for adding tokens to its replacement-text.

Hereby amounts of consecutive hashes get halved:

```latex
\def\reptemp{Some hashes: ########}
\show\reptemp
\expandafter\edef\expandafter\reptemp\expandafter{\reptemp, 1}
\show\reptemp
\expandafter\edef\expandafter\reptemp\expandafter{\reptemp, 2}
\show\reptemp
% The following yields: "! Illegal parameter number in definition of \reptemp."
%\expandafter\edef\expandafter\reptemp\expandafter{\reptemp, 3}
%\show\reptemp
\stop
```

(Here `\edef` was used. Halving of hashes also takes place when using `\def`/`\gdef`/`\xdef`.)

In order to prevent this you can have things wrapped into `\unexpanded`:

```latex
\newcommand\extendmystringmacro[3]{%
  \edef#1{\unexpanded{#2}\unexpanded\expandafter{#1#3}}%
}%
\def\reptemp{I \textit{love} rain}
\show\reptemp
\begingroup
\extendmystringmacro{\reptemp}{}{, but \textbf{not} too much.}
\show\reptemp
\extendmystringmacro{\reptemp}{}{ Some hashes:  ########}
\show\reptemp
\extendmystringmacro{\reptemp}{A, }{, 1}
\show\reptemp
\extendmystringmacro{\reptemp}{B, }{, 2}
\show\reptemp
\global\extendmystringmacro{\reptemp}{C, }{, 3}
\endgroup
\show\reptemp
\stop
```

... or into a token-register but then prefixing with `\global` etc won't work:

```latex
\makeatletter
\newcommand\exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\newcommand\extendmystringmacro[3]{%
  \expandafter\exchange\expandafter{%
    \expandafter\toks@\expandafter{\the\toks@}%
  }{%
    \toks@{#2}%
    \toks@\expandafter{\the\expandafter\toks@#1#3}%
    \edef#1{\the\toks@}%
  }%
}%
\makeatother
\def\reptemp{I \textit{love} rain}
\show\reptemp
\extendmystringmacro{\reptemp}{}{, but \textbf{not} too much.}
\show\reptemp
\extendmystringmacro{\reptemp}{}{ Some hashes: ########}
\show\reptemp
\extendmystringmacro{\reptemp}{A, }{, 1}
\show\reptemp
\extendmystringmacro{\reptemp}{B, }{, 2}
\show\reptemp
\extendmystringmacro{\reptemp}{C, }{, 3}
\show\reptemp
\stop
```

(With none of my examples a check was performed for detecting if `\extendmystringmacro`'s first argument indeed consists of a single token which denotes a macro that does not process arguments.)