# xcolor: Append a text from a command argument inside the color name when defining it

Tags: beamer, macros, xetex, color

I'm making a custom style for a presentation with `beamer`. I'm using `\getbeamercolor` to have the foreground and background colors of a given beamer color in `fg` and `bg`, respectively.

I realized I need to get those colors more than once, so I wrote a command to wrap the following code snippet up and call it every time I need it:

```
\newcommand{\getbeamercolors}[1]{%
  \usebeamercolor{#1}%
  \colorlet{fgColor}{fg}%
  \colorlet{bgColor}{bg}%
}
```

Unfortunately, I also need to call that command twice, and get all those colors to use them at the same time. Then I thought I could simply modify the above command to append a suffix to each color, like this:

```
\newcommand{\getbeamercolors}[2]{%
  \usebeamercolor{#1}%
  \colorlet{fg#2}{fg}%
  \colorlet{bg#2}{bg}%
}
```

But that didn't work. I even looked for an answer on this site, and I even read [this](http://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=23579), but to no avail.

Is there a way to append a text from a command argument inside the color name when defining it?

Simple MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\getbeamercolors}[1]{%
  \usebeamercolor{#1}%
  \colorlet{fgColor}{fg}%
  \colorlet{bgColor}{bg}%
}

% This didn't work!
%\newcommand{\getbeamercolors}[2]{%
%  \usebeamercolor{#1}%
%  \colorlet{fg#2}{fg}%
%  \colorlet{bg#2}{bg}%
%}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{This is a test!}
        \getbeamercolors{frametitle}{title}
        Some text to color with \texttt{\textbackslash getbeamercolors}...

        \textcolor{bgColor}{Text with frame title background color.}

        \colorbox{black}{\textcolor{fgColor}{Text with frame title foreground color.}}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If I uncomment the second definition and change the frame body to have `\textcolor{bgtitle}` and `\textcolor{fgtitle}` I get the same picture in your answer.

Answer (score 5):

Without defining new colours, you could simply use the already defined beamer colours:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{This is a test!}

            \usebeamercolor{frametitle}

            normal text

            \textcolor{frametitle.bg}{Text with frame title background color.}

            \colorbox{black}{\textcolor{frametitle.fg}{Text with frame title foreground color.}}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

---

Off topic: you don't need `xcolor` as beamer already provides this functionality for you.

Comment: It is sometimes handy to get a beamer colour and use it as a new colour, e.g. when such  a colour is used at different places (in a new command, as a `listing`'s `keywordstyle`, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it! I used the `etoolbox` package, as [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74709/101590) explained.

**UPDATE:** Be sure to load *first* the color theme, otherwise the command won't work!

MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\getbeamercolors}[2]{%
  \usebeamercolor{#1}%
  \def\backName{back}
  \def\foreName{fore}
  \appto\backName{#2}
  \appto\foreName{#2}
  \colorlet{\foreName}{fg}%
  \colorlet{\backName}{bg}%
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{This is a test!}
        \getbeamercolors{frametitle}{title}
        Some text to color with \texttt{\textbackslash getbeamercolors}...

        \textcolor{backtitle}{Text with frame title background color.}

        \colorbox{black}{\textcolor{foretitle}{Text with frame title foreground color.}}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Output of given MWE]