# Redefine macro without using tmp variable

Tags: macros, tex-core

Is it possible to amend to a macro without storing the original one in a tmp variable?

Approach is similar to this one here: [Redefine macro in terms of old one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51401/redefine-macro-in-terms-of-old-one). But without the `OldMacro`

I came up with something using groups, but doesn't work.

```
\def\abc{abc} 
\begingroup\let\orgabc\abc\def\abc{\orgabc\endgroup def}
```

---

**EDIT:** It's indeed partially working. But not to my expectations.

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\abc{abc}
\begingroup\let\orgabc\abc\def\abc{\orgabc\endgroup def}

\begin{document}
  \abc
\end{document}
```

Output: abcdef (Works, as expected)

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\abc{abc}
\begingroup\let\orgabc\abc\def\abc{\orgabc\endgroup def}

\begin{document}
  \abc
  \abcorg
\end{document}
```

Output: Error: undefined control sequence (Works as desired, because `\abcorg` is not defined)

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\abc{abc}
\begingroup\let\orgabc\abc\def\abc{\orgabc\endgroup def}

\begin{document}
  \orgabc
\end{document}
```

Output: abc (Why is `\orgabc` defined here?)

---

**EDIT:** The redefinition somehow clashes with the titlesec package. I opened a new question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/356130/redefining-macro-clashes-with-titlesec-package-how-to-avoid)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: What is your goal? For me it prints `abcdef`.

Comment: In LaTeX there is `\g@addto@macro`, so `\g@addto@\abc{foo}` →`\abc ` expands to `abcfoo` then

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I now understand the power of the MWE. It does indeed work in a MWE, but doesn't in my main document. I will edit my question.

Comment: Ooops, I meant `\g@addto@macro\abc{foo}` above...

Comment: Well, effectively you use a temp 'variable' anyway

Comment: Yes, but I don't want the tmp token to be defined outside the redefinition. How is this handled by `\g@addto@macro\abc{foo}`?

Comment: @Simon: both the original macro as well as the addto - content are stored in a temp token register and the original macro is redefined with `\xdef` ... all a in group, so the temp token is volatile actually, but the crucial point is the expansion such that the temp token 'releases' its value

Comment: [This answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39750/29394) shows how `\g@addto@macro` is implemented.

Comment: With this approach the changes to `\abc` are only valid for its first use; thereafter it reverts to its previous definition. Is that the desired behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This of course cannot work, because it will leave the effect of `\begingroup` hanging until you *call* `\abc`, which will probably happen in undesirable places (see your other question).

To me it seems you want to do

```
\def\abc{abc}
\expandafter\def\expandafter\abc\expandafter{\abc def}
```

but this is clumsy and limited to only allow appending.

Without reinventing the wheel, you can use `etoolbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\abc}{abc}

\begin{document}

The macro \verb|\abc| expands to ``\abc''.

\appto\abc{def}

The macro \verb|\abc| expands to ``\abc''.

\preto\abc{X}\appto\abc{X}

The macro \verb|\abc| expands to ``\abc''.

\end{document}
```

This will print

> The macro `\abc` expands to “abc”.
>   The macro `\abc` expands to “abcdef”.
>   The macro `\abc` expands to “XabcdefX”.

Answer (score 5):

Reorganized and corrected my answer

The cause why `\orgabc` is still available is that the group is actually never closed, it causes warnings about `semi groups`.

Now, egreg has used `\expandafter\def\....` already.

It is possible to use `\xdef\foo{\foo other stuff}` to use a shorter version.

As a third variant, apply `\g@addto@macro` from the LaTeX kernel, which stores everything expanded in a token first and redefines the macro with `\xdef`, in order to expand the token.

```
\documentclass{article}



\def\abc{abc}
\def\abcother{abc}
\def\abcyetanother{abc}
\expandafter\def\expandafter\abc\expandafter{\abc\ defappended which works}

\xdef\abcother{\abcother\ defappended works as well}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\abcyetanother{\ and here again}

\makeatother


\begin{document}
First version: \abc

Second version:  \abcother

Third version: \abcyetanother
\end{document}
```

[image]