# Redefining macro clashes with titlesec package. How to avoid?

Tags: tex-core, titlesec

In my question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/356120/redefine-macro-without-using-tmp-variable) how to properly add to a macro without storing the original one in a tmp variable, I was told that my code is actually working. However, it somehow clashes with the titlesec package.

How can I change my code to properly work along the titlesec package while still not defining a tmp variable for the original macro?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\def\abc{abc}
\begingroup\let\orgabc\abc\def\abc{\orgabc\endgroup def}

\begin{document}
  \section{One}
  \abc

  \section{Two}
  Two

\end{document}
```

Works fine with `\usepackage{titlesec}` commented out!

Comment: Is that really the definition of `\abc` that you want, with or without the titlesec package it wil completely break latex as it puts `\begin{document}` inside a group, also if you use `\abc` more than once you will get an error over an unmatched `\endgroup`. Surely you do not want the `\endgroup` to be in the definition of `\abc` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Is this a `tex-core` or a `latex-base` question?

Comment: @erreka marginal either way but tex-core I think as mostly it's about `\def` and `\endgroup`

Answer (score 6):

```
\def\abc{abc}
\begingroup\let\orgabc\abc\def\abc{\orgabc\endgroup def}

\begin{document}
  \section{One}
  \abc
```

This would place `\begin{document}` inside a group started by `\begingroup` and ended by `\abc`.

Any environment other than `document` this would generate an error. It does not generate an error message here for technical reasons but it completely breaks all latex processing as all the setup that normally happens at `\begin{document}` will be discarded at `\abc`

Depending on the intention you could do

```
\def\abc{abc}
\let\orgabc\abc
\def\abc{\orgabc def}

\begin{document}
  \section{One}
  \abc
```

or

```
\def\abc{abc}
\expandafter\def\expandafter\abc\expandafter{\abc def}

\begin{document}
  \section{One}
  \abc
```

or

```
\makeatletter
\def\abc{abc}
\g@addto@macro\abc{def}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \section{One}
  \abc
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually your code is equivalent to

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\begingroup
\begin{document}
\section{One}
\endgroup

\section{Two}
  Two

\end{document}
```

but `titlesec` use `\AtBeginDocument{...\let\ttl@Hy@refstepcounter\refstepcounter...}`
so after the `\endgroup` i.e after `\abc` in your code `\ttl@Hy@refstepcounter` is no more defined.

Comment: breaking titlesec is the least of the problems, it means any definitions that happen at begin document are discarded at the group end, so default document fonts, math setup, any `\label` information from the aux file....